# C++: Disassemble a flat vector into multiple vectors of equal size without copying

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Is it possible in C++ to split a flat vector (or C style array) into multiple vectors of equal size without copying any of its containing data? That is, disassembling the original vector by moving its content to a new vector, which invalidates the original vector. The following code example should illustrate this:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

void f(int* v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        v[i] = i;
    }
}

/**
 * Split v into n vectors of equal size without copy its data (assert v.size() % n == 0)
 */
std::vector<std::vector<int>> g(std::vector<int> v, int n) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vs(n);
    int vec_size = v.size() / n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        vs[i].assign(v.begin() + i * vec_size, v.begin() + (i + 1) * vec_size); // copies?
        // how to let vs[i] point to v.begin() + i * vec_size?
    }
    return vs;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v(100);
    f(v.data());
    
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vs = g(std::move(v), 10);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            assert(vs[i][j] == i * 10 + j);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: no need for that useless `f()`, just use [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) to init the vector

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to reuse the memory allocated by the original vector. It is not possible. It might be possible if you write your own allocator, but I do not see the full picture. Or maybe you are looking for `std::span`. If your concern is speed, first run some tests.

Comment: @zdf My main concern is speed. The array is filled by an external library (onnxruntime) and I plan to return a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` instead of a flat structure with paddings. If there's no simple way doing that, I'll resort to copying (and I suppose, writing custom allocators is probably not that simple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in my opinion this is possible. Moving the elements, but not copying the elements.

C++ offers `std::make_move_iterator`. Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator) about that.

To check that, I created a small class to output, to see, if we copy or move something.

So, if your data can "move", then it will work, otherwise of course a copy will be made. With the following we see the result.

```
struct Test {
    int data{};

    Test(int d) : data(d) { std::cout << "Construct and init\n"; }
    Test() { std::cout << "Default construct\n"; };
    ~Test() { std::cout << "Destruct\n"; };
    Test(const Test& other) { std::cout << "Construct\n"; data = other.data; }
    Test(const Test&& other) noexcept { std::cout << "Move Construct\n"; data = other.data; }
    Test& operator =(const Test& other) noexcept { std::cout << "Assign\n"; data = other.data; return *this; }
    Test& operator =(const Test&& other) noexcept { std::cout << "Move Assign\n"; data = other.data; return *this; }
};
```

We will additionally add a small function, which calculates the offsets of the chunks that will be moved.

And then, we can come up with a small function to implement that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>

// Calculate start and end index for all chunks
std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> calculatePairs(const size_t low, const size_t high, const size_t numberOfGroups) {

    // Here we will store the resulting pairs with start and end values
    std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> pairs{};

    // Calculate chung size and remainder
    const size_t delta = high - low;
    const size_t chunk = delta / numberOfGroups;
    size_t remainder = delta % numberOfGroups;

    // Calculate the chunks start and end addresses for all chunks
    size_t startIndex{}, endIndex{};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfGroups; ++i) {

        // Calculate end address and distribute remainder equally
        endIndex = startIndex + chunk + (remainder ? 1 : 0);
        // Store a new pair of start and end indices
        pairs.emplace_back(startIndex, endIndex);
        // Next start index
        startIndex = endIndex;
        // We now consumed 1 remainder
        if (remainder) --remainder;
    }
    //--pairs.back().second;
    return pairs;
}

struct Test {
    int data{};

    Test(int d) : data(d) { std::cout << "Construct and init\n"; }
    Test() { std::cout << "Default construct\n"; };
    ~Test() { std::cout << "Destruct\n"; };
    Test(const Test& other) { std::cout << "Construct\n"; data = other.data; }
    Test(const Test&& other) noexcept { std::cout << "Move Construct\n"; data = other.data; }
    Test& operator =(const Test& other) noexcept { std::cout << "Assign\n"; data = other.data; return *this; }
    Test& operator =(const Test&& other) noexcept { std::cout << "Move Assign\n"; data = other.data; return *this; }
};

std::vector<std::vector<Test>> split(std::vector<Test>& v, unsigned int n) {
    std::vector<std::vector<Test>> result{};
    if (v.size() > n) {

        result.resize(n);
        std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> offset = calculatePairs(0u, v.size(), n);

        for (size_t i{}; i < n; ++i) {
            result[i].insert(result[i].end(), std::make_move_iterator(v.begin() + offset[i].first),
                std::make_move_iterator(v.begin() + offset[i].second));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

constexpr size_t NumberOfElements = 30u;
constexpr unsigned int NumberOfGroups = 3;
static_assert (NumberOfElements >= NumberOfGroups, "Number of elements must be greater/equal then number of elements\n");

int main() {
    std::cout << "\n\n\nCreate vector with " << NumberOfElements << " elements\n\n";
    std::vector<Test> v1(NumberOfElements);

    std::cout << "\n\n\nFill vector with std::iota\n\n";
    std::iota(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 1);

    std::cout << "\n\n\nSplit in " << NumberOfGroups<< "\n\n";
    std::vector<std::vector<Test>> s = split(v1, NumberOfGroups);

    std::cout << "\n\n\nOutput\n\n";
    for (const std::vector<Test>& vt : s) {
        for (const Test& d : vt) std::cout << std::setw(3) << d.data << ' ';
        std::cout << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

---

But my strong guess is that you want to splice the data. The underlying elements fo the `std::vector` which you can get with the `data()` function.

You can access the data easily with pointer arithmetic on `data()`.

But if you want to have the data in a new container, then this is difficult with a `std::vector`. It can for example be done with a `std::list` that has a `splice` function and does, what you want.

Or, you need to implement your own dynamic array and implement a splice function . . .

---

Checksum:

;23M#eTo1?:B#r7C8#wtJ'Z'..uIv*LT.j;bld$Bvgjd.qm=8;B/*`dHM%D@wyv:\5YI:WVGwJL00%IsKQ9O+&@g,/gzkPg^cg::LX?6*dL3;Fs3GOOAmQmCIW?&skWxZXsE`lyn6S3@fi:0DSKJ/A^r#*'k#a#e8!XDpjAUtu?K5iu+e=P"M7a2BWdFdA.5NP:Y"l,,h+Y/PxhVfP/m0ceS=Nxol2vOZwM2+!H\^a=douX%fhqcr4'0eXiEZeKvTf0^%CTNY^WB6fc#IpK^GQgxTXQo0ikr0+/OxXlc1B$5jc1r,GQj+fwEdoCPrz6,j:SO6L3QU#7lT:f#Y^V!Au\P'a5amR$NCU?\WspBOuy#RH3tJimka#rdyNN56.$;DtRCHN*YeWlrG=',XNSrzEK:Cw;@A%.@/:c,a2W24IIIdecc7O"EnKQn;nXmUemX4kclDsYci+izmr#vlGAQ.w2!cuf;6n2UvJM,CeSyRj1,:2\9#i8GLwtux!uEHUp7X*5SC%nld956CHsy&/n73/90cRP'Me"1PW+@#FH8mH4Rf^o=ZP/Rm\X&1syUdUh+.N/jtoO:,OBBAmq,jW69Fu%jJukBa$g4hIrIPcxx17i;XU,FCbQGd8v*AyKGSML\JN#jte*F";Zh7fqhvCXobE&SapX90r"Z$.CN,1R^aj.=5L6^tUB2UPJH^eb'*B!v5=D.9PFI#Pt*KjK+yS*tV6f.5kgPOzBE$uK0MA/\l9U"63LUR6k3#'cub?u&xILMXP%@:lx2TbKhFOjBpMN!+%F16jrgv&AoFhuf%P!==8?x,NsSd%hVo"BJhVv`3rjrhvM"WLE3%y#N7g37Re^XiS9lpyKA9E7ow6U=I"tlv",&@+fZoIR4KM58!NTm978wCI?9wo.ocS!9i5k@l`er47J.G0yXjZVSdr=G"uRodC06k\V%8;o`UwV&z!W5:+ZvE:nyO#+lO+Hn0&tnH&^tNC?'PmERxs/B+KW4O6&oWDED9?M*qxmYgVKoT.a%iw

Comment: The gist of your solution is using `std::make_move_iterator`. Moving an object doesn't necessarily mean, it's not physically moved or copied in memory, right? If I initialize a vector with integers and use `std::make_move_iterator` to move its contents to a new vector, the old vector's content remains valid and the new vector contains the same data. The memory address of the new vector differs from the old vector though, so clearly, some data was copied around in memory. `std::list` is an alternative worth to check out. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I understand, your solution is applicable to cases where the vector elements are moveable classes.